# MySQL - Inner join taking too long

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a simple Inner join that takes too long (Stopped the query on 10 minutes). It joins 2 tables Table A and B.

Using Describe Command returns the following information

```
+--------+---------------+-------------+----------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  type  | possible_keys |     key     |  key_len |  ref |   rows  |                     extra                    |
+--------+---------------+-------------+----------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| index  | NULL          | myWallet    |       56 | NULL | 4007793 | Using index                                  |
| index  | NULL          | myTransaction|      213| NULL |   45260 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer  |
+--------+---------------+-------------+----------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+

Table A 
myTransaction
myWallet
amount

Table B
myWallet
RegistrationDate

SELECT a.myTransaction, a.myWallet, b.RegistrationDate, a.amount 
FROM mytable.tableA a
INNER JOIN mytable.tableB b 
ON a.myWallet = b.myWallet
```

Any suggestion on how to speed up this Inner Join?

Comment: How many records has the result? Do you really need to grab all those records?

Comment: yeah i really need to grab all those records.

Comment: Do you have index on `myWallet` column in `myTransaction` table?

Comment: You really need to provide SHOW CREATE TABLE results for all relevant tables